# View browser video with gitlab CI using selenium/standalone-chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

I have a Docker Desktop setup for running local tests using the selenium/standalone-chrome Docker container, which serves two ports - 4444 for Selenium and 7900 for a noVNC player where I can see the browser and the tests in real time.

Is there a way to see the noVNC player or to create a recording of the browser from GIT? My tests run locally without error but they fail during the build in GIT and the test logs do not give enough information to know why they are failing, which is why I want to see what is happening during the test.

I could not find a definitive answer or solution while searching for this.

I am using Selenium with JavaScript to test the front-end functionality of a cloud-based platform

Answer (score 0):

If possible, replicate the GitLab CI environment locally using Docker, and then run your tests. This way, you can use the same Docker setup and potentially reproduce the issue locally, allowing for easier debugging.

Comment: This is what I have, I have the whole setup locally, but the tests outcome is different.